# Engines for creating installers

Tags: installation, nsis

I'm looking for installation creator engines. I've checked [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) and [NDJS](http://ndjs.io/).

I would like to request for some additional information about them, or another tools I could use.

- I'm not quite to figuring out whether they are tools in order for me to able to creator installer for several platforms
- What's the state of NDJS? Both have not a good documentation. I'm not quite to able to figure out how's their state
- Are both useful for .NET developed projects?
- Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also **Inno Setup** which is free and amazing installation system.

I am not sure about NDJS but I can recommend NSIS and Inno Setup (see disclaimer below).

Both *NSIS and Inno Setup* are excellent. They are *open source*, well documented (yes this is true!), with *large community* and active development (NSIS has new release 3 days ago even during Christmas!).

*NSIS is C like* scripting language but a little more difficult to start with. *Inno Setup is Pascal like* language easier to learn.

Their *capabilities are unlimited* because of their scripting nature: you can do everything in them and even wrote C/C++/pascal/C# (maybe other) plug-ins if you need to execute something really special. They are useful for any Windows apps (native, .NET, plugin-s, drivers, firmware, from small apps to enterprise solutions).

To start with .net installer (Inno Setup) try e.g. this code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20868/NET-Framework-Installer-for-InnoSetup

Disclaimer:

I tried several other commercial install system  systems but none of them offered the same as NSIS/Inno Setup (for free). I use NSIS and Inno Setup daily and I recommend them as best install system available.

I am NSIS and Inno Setup professional and I develop professional installers in this systems (http://www.unsigned.sk). I also developed Microsoft Visual Studio and Embarcadero RAD studio extensions which integrate NSIS and Inno Setup into these IDEs and Graphical Installer which is skinning engine for installers.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Slappy said I would like add Microsoft Xml type installer i.e. Wix into your list. Thought NSIS/Inno is a beautiful piece of tool to build installer system, Wix is more modern and directly accessible from Visual Studio projects.

Learning curve of Wix is a bit hard than these scripting languages but many companies are now using this Wix tool.